# Where can I see the build script used by Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, assemblies, build-process

Where can I find the build script -all the list of tools used to build and link the assemlies like al.exe etc.-that BUILDS, REBUILDS the visual-Studio solutions?

Answer (score 3):

MSBuild (the build engine for Visual Studio) uses a model where the tool(s) used for an action are dictated by the project file being built.  Thus your list of tools will vary based on the types of projects you are building.  The easiest way to find out the list of tools being used for a build of any given solution would be to turn on a more detailed logging level (detailed or diag) for MSBuild via Tools->Options->Projects & Solutions->Build & Run in Visual Studio and then parse/investigate the build output for an indication of the tools currently invoked by the Build Targets.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to see the detailed output. But I see: Task "Csc"
Done executing task "Csc". but it does not show how it called csc.exe. Is it somehow possible to see the entire call to execute the csc let's say?

Comment: if you aren't seeing the csc.exe commandline in the log, then you aren't running in detailed mode. When in detailed mode, the log should show something like: Task "Csc"
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /war
  n:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE;SILVERLIGHT /reference:...

Answer (score 3):

As Nick Nieslanik has said in his answer, the actual toolset will vary based on the project type (and target programming language), maybe even the selected .NET framework version.

To have single view on all definitions, properties, targets, etc. used by MSBuild, you could generate and review a fully preprocessed project file (only available with MSBuild 4.0 or newer).

From `msbuild.exe /?` output:

```
  /preprocess[:file]
                     Creates a single, aggregated project file by
                     inlining all the files that would be imported during a
                     build, with their boundaries marked. This can be
                     useful for figuring out what files are being imported
                     and from where, and what they will contribute to
                     the build. By default the output is written to
                     the console window. If the path to an output file
                     is provided that will be used instead.
                     (Short form: /pp)
                     Example:

                   /pp:out.txt
```

Example:

```
msbuild.exe myproj.csproj /pp:out.xml
```

In this case `out.xml` is basically a self-contained file that has all the `Import`-ed project files inline so you can easily search and browse them.

Answer (score 0):

In each project (in this case a c# csproj) file is a link to the msbuild used by msbuild/visual studio to build.

e.g. `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`

This target links to the internal files used.